# Ordering array according to index ~ text

Tags: arrays, r, indexing

Please, put in `R` these datas:

```
S.names <- c("FXI", "XLB", "GLD", "IWM", "XLE", "XLF", "EWZ", "GDX", "XLK", 
"TLT", "IYR", "QQQ", "SLV", "EWJ", "XLV", "DIA", "XHB", "EEM", 
"USO", "VWO", "SPY", "EFA")
strike_vec <- structure(list(Strike = c(152, 43, 61, 11, 56, 37, 36, 159, 96, 
74, 71, 27, 163, 128, 35, 44, 30, 40, 81, 19, 31, 48)), .Names = "Strike", row.names = 
c("DIA", "EEM", "EFA", "EWJ", "EWZ", "FXI", "GDX", "GLD", "IWM", "IYR", 
"QQQ", "SLV", "SPY", "TLT", "USO", "VWO", "XHB", "XLB", "XLE", 
"XLF", "XLK", "XLV"), class = "data.frame")
```

As you can see, `strike_vec` row names are equal to `S.names` elements.

I would like to order `strike_vec` elements according to the order of `S.names`, that is associating each `strike_vec` element to the position in which you find the corresponding `S.names` row name.

The final result should be something like

```
> strike_vec.new
    [,1]
FXI   37
XLB   40
GLD  159
IWM   96
   ...
   ...
   ...
```

where `rownames(strike_vec.new)` follows exactly the order of `S.names`.

How may I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use :

```
strike_vec[S.names,,drop=FALSE]
```

Which gives :

```
    Strike
FXI     37
XLB     40
GLD    159
IWM     96
XLE     81
XLF     19
EWZ     56
GDX     36
XLK     31
TLT    128
IYR     74
QQQ     71
SLV     27
EWJ     11
XLV     48
DIA    152
XHB     30
EEM     43
USO     35
VWO     44
SPY    163
EFA     61
```

This works because if you index the rows of a data frame with a character vector, indexing will be based on row names.